# Android Palette doesn't work?

Tags: android, colors, palette

I want to use the Palette API but it always gives me bad colors, doesn't matter what my combinations are. I tried to generate the swatches with **numColor** 16, 24, 32, 500, 1000 and use the vibrant, dark vibrant, muted, light vibrant etc... colors, but nothing worked. 
I want to extract the colors from an image and get colors like in these apps: [YouTube](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWEB6.jpg), [Music App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxPYO.jpg). How can I achieve this appearance?

Comment: What does "bad colors" mean? Does it just not return colors that you find aesthetically pleasing? Please post examples.

Comment: Sometimes it doesn't return anything. I made a screenshot for you:

Comment: checkout this example http://code2concept.blogspot.in/2015/10/android-support-v7-palette-demo.html

Answer (score 1):

So this is the result with the **same** image:

[How it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qosvc.jpg),
[Mine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEBc7.png)

Comment: I got pink instead of the gray colors. When I try other swatches it isn't better.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed a bug in the Android sample code that would lead to grey swatches appearing pink. There is a routine called make565() that is improperly coded. It should read:

```
static uint16_t  make565(int red, int green, int blue)
{
    return (uint16_t)( ((red   << 8) & 0xf800) |
                       ((green << 3) & 0x07e0) |
                       ((blue  >> 3) & 0x001f) );
}
```